# lxc command always "get error 4 in libc-2.12.so"

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, lxc

I've tried several time to find out why suddenly my LXC not working, I use `dmesg | tail` it shows:

```
lxc-start[2777]: segfault at fffffffffffffffc ip 000000390347b82c sp 00007fffd9046c18 error 4 in libc-2.12.so[3903400000+18b000]

lxc-start[3311]: segfault at fffffffffffffffc ip 000000390347b82c sp 00007fff332ece98 error 4 in libc-2.12.so[3903400000+18b000]

lxc-console[3327]: segfault at fffffffffffffffc ip 000000390347b82c sp 00007fffdddb9218 error 4 in libc-2.12.so[3903400000+18b000]

lxc-start[3402]: segfault at fffffffffffffffc ip 000000390347b82c sp 00007fffb366aea8 error 4 in libc-2.12.so[3903400000+18b000]

lxc-destroy[3472]: segfault at fffffffffffffffc ip 000000390347b82c sp 00007fff58b63e78 error 4 in libc-2.12.so[3903400000+18b000]
```

I've looked out for the problem in any website or forums but I have no luck to found the solution.

Comment: Typical case of a negative nullpointer dereference. The problem isn't in your libc, but in your lxc. In your place I recompiled lxc.